# Vue - Ckeditor with Multiple extraPlugins

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ckeditor, embed, autogrow

I'm using vue-ckeditor2 on my website, alongside Laravel. I'm trying to figure out how to use multiple extraplugins.

Doing this works, but it ends up with only one extraPlugin - Embed:

```
                'BulletedList',
                'Image',
                'Source',
                'Format',
                'Link',
                'Unlink',
                'Embed',
            ]
        ],
        extraPlugins: 'embed',
        toolbarLocation: 'bottom',
    }
}
```

This works as well, but I end up with only one - Autogrow:

```
                'Format',
                'Link',
                'Unlink',
            ]
        ],
        extraPlugins: 'autogrow',
        toolbarLocation: 'bottom',
    }
}
```

However, combinding them in a way I've found online doesn't work, and actually makes the textarea disappear all together:

```
                'Unlink',
                'Embed',
            ]
        ],
        extraPlugins: 'autogrow, embed',
        toolbarLocation: 'bottom',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try remove the space after the comma so your example should be as follows:

```
extraPlugins: 'autogrow,embed',
```

Assuming that the Vue2-CKEditor follows CKEditor conventions regarding extra plugins, see [here](https://docs-old.ckeditor.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.extraPlugins).